# BTRFS error that keeps remounting as read-only due to previous I/O errors. How to proceed?

Tags: ubuntu, backup, btrfs

I have four drives as RAID-10. I've been having I/O errors on my system due to unknown reasons and been having to redo the volume a couple of times. Each time another drive has the I/O errors. I thinks it's either because of bad cables or power supply.

However when I created the current volume, one of my drives kept showing a lot of errors. Still I was so happy I had the Raid "working" that I didn't want to do anything about it.

Now I think I got the I/O errors down after replaced cables. Still when I mount my RAID volume I get this in dmesg:

```
BTRFS: error (device dm-5) in btrfs_drop_snapshot:9496: errno=-5 IO failure
```

Also I get errors such as

```
bad tree block start
parent transid verify failed on
```

I've tried mounting as recovery with all drives, and as degraded without the drive that's been having the I/O errors (there are a lot of them).

I havent been successfull in getting any more info about the btrfs_drop_snapshot but I guess it's something about a failing snapshopt from before I replaced the cables.

Also, I've zeroed the journal and did a successfull chunk recovery.
Stil no avail regarding the error message that remounts the volume as read-only. Scub fails after a few gigabytes.

I'm using a cronjob for snapshots.

Is there any way forward regarding this or do I need to redo the volume from scratch again?

What if I delete the previously failing drive and add it again?

Can I through away the snapshot (if that's the case) that's failing?

Thanks in advance,
Daniel

Running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

```
$ uname -r
5.0.0-37-generic

Btrfs-progs
Version: 4.15.1-1build1
```

Comment: Marc Merlins wrote some stuff about how to recover such a file system: http://marc.merlins.org/perso/btrfs/post_2014-03-19_Btrfs-Tips_-Btrfs-Scrub-and-Btrfs-Filesystem-Repair.html